# How can I setup passwordless email signin in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links, password-less

I'm trying to setup passwordless authentification in Firebase. I already enabled "email without password" auth in my Project settings.
Using this documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_link_for_sign-in I managed to implement a way to create auth links.
My goal is to open https://dev.test.com/signup/ with the email of the user so he will be instantly signed in.

This is my code so far:

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth


def main():
    default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()

    email = 'name.chris@gmail.com'
    action_code_settings = auth.ActionCodeSettings(
        url=f'https://dev.test.com/signup/?email={email}',
        handle_code_in_app=True,
        ios_bundle_id='com.example.ios',
        android_package_name='com.example.android',
        android_install_app=True,
        android_minimum_version='12',
        dynamic_link_domain='magic42.page.link',
    )

    link = auth.generate_sign_in_with_email_link(email, action_code_settings)
    print(f"LINK = {link}")
```

When I click on the link, I don't get automatically signed in. I guess I should also modify my front end. I'm using Angular. My signup looks like this :

```js
  signUp(email: string, password: string): Observable<UserCredential> {
    const credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
    return from(firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused why you have email and password on frontend. To complete sign in using the email link, you should be using `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink()` method and not linkWithCredential on your /signup page.

You can get sample code (which should be executed on your /signup page) of completing sign in with email link in the documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth

Comment: I have email and password on frontend because I didn't change anything from previous authentification : email + password. So I should change this, right ? How should I pass the email ? Directly in the URL like I did ?

Comment: @cuzureau okay but when you are using email link auth you should use signInWithEmailLink method. It takes 2 parameters as in documentation. 1st one is email of thay user and 2nd one is the email link itself. I'd say just copy the code from the docs I've shared and paste it on your signup page such that it runs immediately after page load. The flow is, user clicks on link, firebase authenticates user on its own domain and then redirect to your sign up page

Comment: This [code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#completing_sign-in_in_a_web_page) doesn't work. It requires to store the email of the user in window.localStorage. But sending a link from the backend like I did doesn't allow to store anything on window.localStorage on the frontend. So the user has to type again its email which is not the behavior we want. I cannot also pass the email in te URL (I did it by mistake in my code) because of security reasons : "Do not pass the user’s email in the redirect URL parameters and re-use it as this may enable session injections."

Comment: @cuzureau you need to store email in local storage when user enters it else they would have to manually enter it when they open the link.... also what do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: I already have all the informations about my user (email, name, birthdate, phone number, etc). I want a link, when clicked, automatically brings the user to our website and authenticate him without having to type any email or password or anything else. Is that possible with Firebase ?

Comment: @cuzureau aren't you using Firebase Authentication? Where is all that information stored? The sign link link requires an email so firebase knows which user it is supposed to login.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235447/discussion-between-cuzureau-and-dharmaraj).

Comment: maybe you could help me on this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710297/can-i-skip-the-first-step-in-the-passwordless-signin-method-in-firebase