# Can I skip the first step in the passwordless signin method in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links, password-less

I have a list of people with all their personal information (name, first name, date of birth, email, etc.).I want to send to each of these people an email with a link allowing them, once clicked, to be directly connected on our website. Without having to type a password.

---

I followed the Firebase procedure for passwordless authentication:

- from the back back in Python. [Generate email link for connexion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_link_for_sign-in)
- for the front in Angular Js. [Completing signin in a web page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#completing_sign-in_in_a_web_page)
- [Fireship.io tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/using-passwordless-signup-with-firebase-on-the-web/)

But most of the examples don't quite fit my use case.

Most of the examples:

1. User comes to your website, asks for passwordless authentication, types in his email, (the email is stored in `window.location.href`)
2. User receives an email with a link to log in, he clicks on it
3. User is on your website, logged in (thanks to his email stored in `window.location.href`).

My use case:

1. None. I already have the email of my user, so I send him directly the link to connect.
2. User receives an email with a link to log in, he clicks on it
3. User is on my website, but has to type his e-mail again in the prompt (because it is obviously not stored in `window.location.href`).

In my case the `window.location.href` variable will never be used. And I don't want my user to have to retype his email once the link is clicked. Since I already have his email, why ask him again?

---

**So how can I skip this step? Is there any security risk in doing so?**

---

This is my code so far:

Back:

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth
from google.cloud import firestore


def create_new_auth(dictionary):
    user = auth.create_user(
        email=dictionary['email'],
        email_verified=True,
        phone_number=dictionary['phone'],
        password='super_secure_password_007',
        display_name=f"{dictionary['firstName']} {dictionary['lastName']}",
        disabled=False)
    print('Sucessfully created new user: {0}'.format(user.uid))

    return user.uid


def create_new_pre_user(db, dictionary, uid):
    dictionary = {
        'uid': uid,
        'email': dictionary['email'],
        'lastName': dictionary['lastName'],
        'gender': dictionary['gender'],
        'birthday': dictionary['birthday'],
        'phone': dictionary['phone'],
        'firstName': dictionary['firstName']
    }
    db.collection(u'users').document(uid).set(dictionary)


def main(dictionary):
    firebase_admin.initialize_app()
    db = firestore.Client()
    uid = create_new_auth(dictionary)
    create_new_pre_user(db, dictionary, uid)

    action_code_settings = auth.ActionCodeSettings(
        url=f'http://localhost:4200/login',
        handle_code_in_app=True,
        ios_bundle_id='com.example.ios',
        android_package_name='com.example.android',
        android_install_app=True,
        android_minimum_version='12',
        dynamic_link_domain='magic42.page.link',
    )

    link = auth.generate_sign_in_with_email_link(dictionary['email'], action_code_settings)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dictionary = {
        "firstName": "Jone",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "birthday": 12345678,
        "gender": "male",
        "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
        "phone": "+33611223344"
    }
    main(dictionary)
```

Front:

```js
private signInWithEmail() {
    if (this.authService.isSignInWithEmailLink(window.location.href)) {
      // Additional state parameters can also be passed via URL.
      // This can be used to continue the user's intended action before triggering
      // the sign-in operation.
      // Get the email if available. This should be available if the user completes
      // the flow on the same device where they started it.
      let email = window.localStorage.getItem('emailForSignIn');
      if (!email) {
        // User opened the link on a different device. To prevent session fixation
        // attacks, ask the user to provide the associated email again. For example:
        email = window.prompt('Please provide your email for confirmation');
      }
      // The client SDK will parse the code from the link for you.
      this.authService.signInWithEmailLink(email, window.location.href)
        .then((result) => {
          // Clear email from storage.
          window.localStorage.removeItem('emailForSignIn');
          // You can access the new user via result.user
          // Additional user info profile not available via:
          // result.additionalUserInfo.profile == null
          // You can check if the user is new or existing:
          // result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser
          this.router.navigate(['/patient', 'quiz'])
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Some error occurred, you can inspect the code: error.code
          // Common errors could be invalid email and invalid or expired OTPs.
        });
    }
  }
```

```js
isSignInWithEmailLink(href) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(href);
  }

  signInWithEmailLink(email: string, href: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailLink(email, href)
  }
```

---

**EDITS**

---

The problem is that the front has no knowledge of the user email when he first come the our website using the link. There is a way to pass the `email` information from our server-side to the front but it's in clear in the URL : that's risky and not a good practice according to Firebase itself ([link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#security_concerns))

Like this:

```py
def main(dictionary):
    firebase_admin.initialize_app()
    db = firestore.Client()
    uid = create_new_auth(dictionary)
    create_new_pre_user(db, dictionary, uid)

    action_code_settings = auth.ActionCodeSettings(
        url=f'http://localhost:4200/login/?email=john.doe@gmail.com',
        handle_code_in_app=True,
        ios_bundle_id='com.example.ios',
        android_package_name='com.example.android',
        android_install_app=True,
        android_minimum_version='12',
        dynamic_link_domain='magic42.page.link',
    )

    link = auth.generate_sign_in_with_email_link(dictionary['email'], action_code_settings)
```

So how can I pass the `email` information from the back to the front so that the user doesn't have to type it again when redirected to my website after clicking to my "magic link" ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. " I already have the email of my user, so I send him directly the link to connect." In that case, what is keeping you from calling the API with the user's email address immediately?

Comment: Call which API? To create a new authenticated user ? Or to add all the infos to a firestore collection ? My problem is : I want to create a link, once clicked, log the user instantly without him having to type a email nore a password, nothing. I thought deep links already contained the email of the user in some way. I thought I could use it instead of asking again the user to type it when redirected on my website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do is to create a single-use token on the backend that links to your user's email (or that links to a document in firestore) and have that be in the url. When the user enters the page, make a call to your backend with the token (could be just a simple uuid) and have your backend sign the user in and then expire/remove that token from use.

E.G.

```
https://yoursite.com/44ed3716-2b8f-4068-a445-b05a8fee17c3
```

Frontend sends `44ed3716-2b8f-4068-a445-b05a8fee17c3` to backend...backend sees the token, logs them in, then makes that token no longer valid.

**Update**

To answer your question in the comments below about not needing email link auth anymore through firebase: not necessarily. At that point, you're kind of creating your own email sign-in system (which actually isn't too hard) and somewhat re-inventing the wheel. Adding a token to the url was just a way for you to associate the user with an email without having to actually put the email in the url so that your frontend can know who the user is once your link is clicked. Once the backend sends you the email, you can store it local storage and complete the sign in with firebase normally.

Comment: OK, so to be clear I don't need `email link` type authentification anymore ? How the frontend send the tocken to backend ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no security risk asking the user to type his/her email versus storing it in the `window` storage, and one could argue that it's actually *more* secure to do so. That said, how you can go about doing this:

1. Make sure you have enabled email passwordless authentication.
2. Using the admin SDK, [add each email address to your auth table](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users#import_users_without_passwords) (though I wouldn't set `emailVerified: true` - that will happen when they click the magic link and verify themselves on login.
3. Again using the admin SDK, [generate a magic link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_link_for_sign-in) for each user and send it to them.
4. On your login page (where the magic link takes them), prompt them for their email address and then use that along with the magic link to authenticate. The [sample code provided from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#completing_sign-in_in_a_web_page) shows you how to do this in the `if(!email){ ... }` part of the code where it uses a window prompt to collect the user's email in case the user clicked the link on a separate device or the browser didn't/couldn't store the email address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't want the user to type again his email since I already have it. I want my user to click to the magic link and BOOM be logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the user's email, you can call `firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail` with that email in the client-side JavaScript SDK ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth)), or `generateSignInWithEmailLink` in the server-side Node.js SDK ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#generatesigninwithemaillink)). Both calls take the user's email as an argument.

---

Once the user lands on your site after clicking the link, you can [access their profile with an auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    var uid = user.uid;
    var email = user.email;
  }
});
```

Comment: I have indeed the user's email but only in the server-side. My code is located in a GCP Cloud Function. Like described in my code, I'm already using `generate_sign_in_with_email_link` (in python) to generate the link. This is fine. Now, since the user never went on my website yet, when he will click on the link I gave him, it will be redirected to my website without the variable `window.location.href` being used. The fronty has no knowledge of his email. So he will have to type again his email in the prompt. This is the extra step I want to get rid of. (how can I pass the email to the front?)

Comment: If the user accesses your site after clicking the link, they'll be signed in and you can access their details with an auth state listener as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: After clicking on the link I gave him, the user will be redirected to my website but he won't be automatically signed in. Not before he manually type his email in the prompt. (This is the step I want to get rid of). Auth state listener will not be useful here. I just tested it, it doesn't help. Sure I can get the `uid` and the `email` of the user, but after he typed manually his email into the prompt. How can I bypass that ?